# How do you turn on console logging in the Ember v2 router API?

Tags: ember.js, router

In v1 of the router API, you could set this flag:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  enableLogging: true
});
```

And the router would log state changes to console.log, which was helpful for debugging.  This doesn't seem to work anymore--does anyone know whether there's a new equivalent to this flag?

Comment: I'm suffering through the new-router changes too.. I'm so conflicted about the new changes.. I liked it initially (it's so rails-like!) but so far they seem superficial at best and lacking in scope..arg..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since [1bf0df4](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/commit/1bf0df4c95512dd42687a9b2b5ca3936a11aa09a) commit:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

Comment: my app doesn't use create. it uses extend. And it doesn't seem to be working. What file should this be in? Mine is in /root/app/app.js

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this has yet to be worked out in the master branch, as far as I can tell: I have, however found a relevant comment in the source code:

```
/* For me this comment starts on line 23202 on build v1.0.0-pre.2-233-g2db13c3

In addition to creating your application's router, `Ember.Application` is
also responsible for telling the router when to start routing.

By default, the router will begin trying to translate the current URL into
application state once the browser emits the `DOMContentReady` event. If you
need to defer routing, you can call the application's `deferReadiness()`
method. Once routing can begin, call the `advanceReadiness()` method.

If there is any setup required before routing begins, you can implement a
`ready()` method on your app that will be invoked immediately before routing
begins:

window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  ready: function() {
    this.set('router.enableLogging', true);
  }
});

*/
```

Note that this comment is actually in the source code for the master branch which has already merged in the new routing changes. I would have to conclude that this is a bug, and will probably be worked out in the near future (hopefully).

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that I dug through the source and tried that, and got an error.  I'm assuming it's just not complete yet.